# How can I toggle the element that is clicked and hide all others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide any visible span elements if any is visible, and toggle it again if a element is clicked

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="">element1</a> <span>span1</span>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="">element2</a> <span>span2</span>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="">element3</a> <span>span3</span>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="">element4</a> <span>span4</span>
    <br>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$('.item span').hide();

var all_spans = $('.item a').parent().find('span');

$('.item a').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    // hide all span
    all_spans.hide();
    $this = $(this).parent().find('span');
    // here is what I want to do
    if ($this.is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).parent().find('span').show();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('span').hide();
    }

});
```

live example http://jsfiddle.net/BGSyS/

the issue is when I click for example '`element 1`' '`span1`' is still visible and I want to toggle this

Comment: Your demo seems working, what's the issue?

Comment: @mishik the issue is when i click for example 'element 1' 'span1' is still visible and I want to toggle this

Comment: @AhmadAjmi: Ah, okay, that wasn't completely clear. Fixed my answer.

Comment: @Khanh TO Thanks so much It works like what I want.

Comment: @Ahmad Ajmi: the problem is when you hide all spans, you also hide the current span => all spans have the same state (hidden), and your next line display it again. You have to exclude the current element when hiding and use `toggle` method to toggle its state (simpler than using if to check)

Comment: @@Khanh TO yes the problem is excluding the current from the spans but I didn't know how to do it using .not. Your code is much simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 $('.item span').hide();

$('.item a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    // hide all span
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('span');
    $(".item span").not($this).hide();

    // here is what I want to do
    $this.toggle();

});
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BGSyS/3/)

**Update with explanation:**

The problem is when you hide all spans, you also hide the current span => all spans have the same state (hidden), and your next line display it again. You have to exclude the current element when hiding and use toggle method to toggle its state (simpler than using if to check)

Another problem is try to avoid implicit global by using `var` to declare `$this`:

```
var $this = $(this).parent().find('span');
```

Comment: +1, but you probably want to get rid of that implicit global.

Comment: Khanh TO, T.J. Crowder Thanks guys for the great explanation.

Comment: @KhanhTO  i am amazed. +1. It saved me

Answer (score 5):

It can be much simpler than that: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGSyS/2/)

```
var all_spans = $('.item span').hide();

$('.item a').click(function(e){
    var thisSpan = $(this).parent().find('span'),
        isShowing = thisSpan.is(":visible");

    // Hide all spans
    all_spans.hide();

    // If our span *wasn't* showing, show it
    if (!isShowing) {
        thisSpan.show();
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The main problem with your code was that you were checking whether the `a` element was visible, rather than checking whether the `span` was.

Your code also fell prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) on this line:

```
$this = $(this).parent().find('span');
```

...which creates a global variable `$this` because you didn't declare it anywhere.

Comment: Good explanation and some nice JS developer advice to boot. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all the spans by using a span selector, then using the $(this) keyword to find the span next to the clicked link:

```
$(".item a").click(function() {
  // Hide all item spans
  $(".item span").hide();
  // Show the element next to this
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

begin snippet: js hide: false

language: lang-js

```
function itemshow(n,e){ 
   var idx = "num_"+n;
   $(".item_title").each(function(){
      var idn = $(this).next().attr("id");
      if (idn == idx){
        $("#"+idn).toggle();
      }else{
        $("#"+idn).hide();
      }
   });
}
```

language: lang-css

```
.item_desc{
   display: none;
 }
```

language: lang-html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div_body">
   <div class="item_title" onclick="itemshow(1,this)">        
        1) Question                           
  </div>
      <div class="item_desc"  id="num_1">
        Answer                           
      </div> 
   <div class="item_title" onclick="itemshow(2,this)">        
        2) Question                           
  </div>
      <div class="item_desc"  id="num_2">
        Answer                          
      </div> 
   <div class="item_title" onclick="itemshow(3,this)">        
        3) Question
  </div>
      <div class="item_desc"  id="num_3">
        Answer                          
      </div> 
</div>
```

end snippet

Comment: I encourage you to write a brief explanation of your code and why it works. Thanks.