# Accordian - Hide Already Opened

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to figure out a proper way to hide all child sections opened in my accordion when a new header is clicked. I have included a jsfiddle for what I have so far. Just need a way to close opened sections. Thanks!

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="w3-container">

<h2>Active Accordions</h2>
<p>In this example we add the w3-red class to an active accordion (when the button is clicked on and the content is opened).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black w3-left-align">Open Section 1</button>
<div id="Demo1" class="w3-hide w3-container">
    <p>Some text..</p>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction('Demo2')" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black w3-left-align">Open Section 2</button>
<div id="Demo2" class="w3-hide w3-container">
    <p>Some other text..</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

js

```
function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
        x.previousElementSibling.className = 
        x.previousElementSibling.className.replace("w3-black", "w3-red");
    } else { 
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        x.previousElementSibling.className = 
        x.previousElementSibling.className.replace("w3-red", "w3-black");
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2eda9kz5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use toggle as it will show or hide the matched element. Check out the jQuery doc: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Check also this answer! It explains how to close all other elements but not the one you have clicked.
[JQuery: Toggle Element that is clicked and hide all other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637822/jquery-toggle-element-that-is-clicked-and-hide-all-other)