# jQuery - toggle element that is clicked and hide all other (not immediate parent)

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to build custom menu with a snippet that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637822/jquery-toggle-element-that-is-clicked-and-hide-all-other) on StackOverflow. I understand that the parent() method will refer only to immediate parent so I played little with different methods (like parents(), closest() etc.) to achieve same result (show one, hide all other), only with div that is on more distant. The problem is that that toggle always show or hide all elements or do nothing at all. I am not that familiar with jQuery (just a basics) so I am sorry if the question is some kind of obvious.

Thank you for your help.

One of my attempts:

```js
$('.div-hide p').hide();

$('.item a').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  // hide all span
  var hideAll = $(this).parents().find('p');
  $(".div-hide p").not(hideAll).hide();

  // here is what I want to do
  hideAll.toggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="high-parent">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="">button1</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="">button2</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="">button3</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="">button4</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="div-hide">
    <p>First part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p>Second part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p>Third part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p>Fourth part</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Depending on how long the project goes I would recommend different approaches: if this is just a little playground and you will not use it one week from now, just use the solution from @MilindAnantwar (but beware of dom changes). If you want to use it for a continues project, that just started, I would recommend my solution, which will take a bit more work in the beginning, but will be stable even if you decide to change the structure of the document.

Comment: David, was the answer helpful?

Comment: You were right. Even if that was just playground, It was for use with real project (different, much complex case). So I chose your solution, and with little changes (changed click event selector from <a> to <img> because there was an image inside it) it worked fine. Again, thank you. PS: Sorry for delay, I was wrapping my head with <a> vs <img> problem :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend not to solely rely on the order of things. I would add a data attribute to the items to be displayed.

```js
$('.div-hide p').hide();

$('.item a').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  // hide all span
  $(".div-hide p").hide();

  // show clicked
  const id = e.target.id;
  $(".div-hide p[data-id='"+id+"']").show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="high-parent">
  <div class="item">
    <a id="1" href="">button1</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a id="2" href="">button2</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a id="3" href="">button3</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a id="4" href="">button4</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="div-hide">
    <p data-id="4">Fourth part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p data-id="2">Second part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p data-id="3">Third part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p data-id="1">First part</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's a lot of DOM change to achieve simple task.imagine if its more than 100 element. developer has to do lot of rework

Comment: Yes, but then it would be solid and would work reliably.

Comment: And those things like id's should be implemented anyway, when using and handling click events.

Comment: That's a lot of rework to implement simple functionality.

Comment: doesn't make it better by repeating yourself :) better do the rework now than with 100 elements when there might be a slight change in the dom.

Comment: I don't have to :)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I just wanna add, that if there is an <img> tag wrapped inside <a> I was needed to change selector for click event from $('.item a') to $('.item img'), because <a> worked just with text inside it. Anyway thank you guys.

Answer (score -1):

You can use index of clicked anchor elements parent to target the p tag element and show hide it:

```js
$('.div-hide p').hide();

$('.item a').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  // hide all span
  var hideAll = $('.div-hide').eq($(this).closest('.item').index()).find('p');
  $(".div-hide p").not(hideAll).hide();
  // here is what I want to do
  hideAll.toggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="high-parent">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="">button1</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="">button2</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="">button3</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="">button4</a><br>
  </div>

  <div class="div-hide">
    <p>First part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p>Second part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p>Third part</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-hide">
    <p>Fourth part</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not a very stable solution, which depends on the order to be right and gives you trouble as soon as you change the markup.