# How can I remove a class from asynchronously created node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html contains node with classname 'custom-collection-pagination-list'.

And function asynchronously add li tags inside id with classname "custom-collection-pagination__item".

How to find and remove active class on another li before I add it to target li?

```
$(".custom-collection-pagination-list").on('click', '.custom-collection-pagination__item', function(e) {
  //find and delete here
  e.target.classList.add('paginate-active'); 
})
```

Comment: You'd use the same technique used for many accordion and list structures, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637832/1264804. Just select all siblings via the most convenient means and remove the class.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It's a bit hard to understand with the current wording.

Comment: you can add `$(this).parent().find('.custom-collection-pagination__item').removeClass('paginate-active')` before adding the class to the current clicked etc

Comment: just target and remove all active classes, under a specific parent if needed; don't try to keep track the last one  and all that. it happens so fast you won't see a glitch in the 0.01ms that "there is no active".